# Amazon S3 bucket permission for unauthenticated cognito role user

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have setup an unauthenticated role under Amazon Cognito Identity pool.  My goal is that guest users of my mobile app would be able to upload debugging logs (small text files) to my S3 bucket so I can troubleshoot issues.  I notice I would get "Access Denied" from S3 if I don't modify my S3 bucket permission.  If I add allow "Everyone" to have "Upload/Delete" privilege, the file upload succeeded.  My concern is someone would then be able to upload large files to my bucket and cause a security issue.  What is the recommend configuration for my need above?  I am a newbie to S3 and Cognito.

I am using Amazon AWS SDK for iOS but I suppose this question is platform neutral.

Edit: 
My policy is as follows:

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:GetUser",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:CreateBucket",
        "s3:DeleteBucket",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::import-to-ec2-*", "arn:aws:s3:::<my bucket name>/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to modify the S3 bucket permission, but rather the IAM role associated with your identity pool. Try the following:

1. Visit the [IAM console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#roles).
2. Find the role associated with your identity pool.
3. Attach a policy similar to the following to your role:

   `{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": ["s3:PutObject"],
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"]
   }
   ]
   }`
4. Replace `MYBUCKET` with your bucket name
5. Access your bucket as normal from your application use the iOS SDK and Cognito

You may want to consider limiting permissions further, including `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` to partition your users, but the above policy will get you started.

Comment: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:GetUser",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:CreateBucket",
        "s3:DeleteBucket",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::import-to-ec2-*", "arn:aws:s3:::<my bucket name>/*"]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: The above is my policy but the file upload still failed.

Comment: If you're using the AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider, it caches the credentials used. You can force a refresh to make sure your credentials reflect the new policy. If you're still having problems, please include the code as well as the specific error you are receiving so we can better help diagnose the issue.

Comment: "You can force a refresh to make sure your credentials reflect the new policy." - Refresh where/how?

Comment: @Jasper [The refresh method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html#//api/name/refresh). In normal operation you should not need to call this method, but it can sometimes be useful when testing new policies.

Comment: Bob> Thanks... i am struggling to understand - How is embedding Identity Pool Id in Android Mobile app any safer than embedding Access Keys etc- even Identity Pool Id can be compromised isn't it?

Comment: @Jasper For the unauthenticated use case, Cognito does not currently add additional security, but we are investigating additional mechanisms to enhance security for this use case. AWS's recommendation is still to not embed credentials in your application, regardless of how well they may be scoped down.

Comment: Bob> Is Cognito Id treated as credential (that must not be compromised)? I do have to embed it in app to access S3 in a secure manner. Alternative: Could you not use APK signature as a security mechanism - so that calls emanating from APK (via AWS SDK) will be allowed S3 access for example.

Comment: @Jasper APK signatures are one of the things we are evaluating integrating into the service to better secure unauthenticated identities, but I cannot commit as to when that would be available.

Comment: @BobKinney is there a more exhaustive documentation on security & Cognito while working with AWS resources? Pool Id is a single identification parameter, while Key/Password are two but not recommended. Is Cognito the correct solution for this use case? Should applications avoid directly talking to S3 and instead do that via a server layer (which talks with S3)?

Comment: @TJ- The documentation is constantly evolving, so I cannot point you to an "exhaustive" document, but if you want your application to directly speak to Amazon S3 or other AWS services, Amazon Cognito is the recommended solution. There may be other reasons developers may choose to use a middle tier, such as sharing between users, which are not directly supported via the Amazon Cognito/IAM permissions model.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is incomplete as of 2015, you need to authorize BOTH the role AND the bucket polity in S3 to authorize that Role to write to the bucket. Use s3:PutObject in both cases. The console has wizards for both cases

Comment: As state of 2017 I did not have to alter the bucket policy at all. Setting the S3 rights via the IAM role was sufficient.

Comment: @VolkerRose AWS changed their S3 bucket policy logic after the Verizon hack. You should have received a notification about this. Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

As @einarc said (cannot comment yet), to make it works I had to edit role and Bucket Policy. This is good enough for testing:

Bucket Policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1500742753994",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1500742752148",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::admin1.user1",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Authenticated role's policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```